# How to prevent clicks from passing through a control to the one below it

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a textbox in a groupbox, both with double click events. When I double click in the textbox both events are triggered.

How do I stop clicks in the textbox from passing through to the groupbox? I've tried putting "e.Handled = true;" at the end of the textbox_DoubleClick event but this makes no difference.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because WPF uses a "tunneling / bubbling" model of event propagation, most events begin bubbling UP from the bottom of the visual tree. If you want to catch an event on the way *down*, there are `Preview` versions of the events that tunnel downwards. For example:

[PreviewMouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.previewmousedoubleclick.aspx)

Set `e.Handled = true` in there.

Answer (score 5):

In your GroupBox's DoubleClick event you could check the value of `e.OriginalSource` and if that value is not the `GroupBox`, ignore the event

```
private void TabItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.OriginalSource is GroupBox)
    { 
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

I believe ClickEvents are actually Direct Events, and not Tunneled/Bubbled events, so setting `e.Handled` in one won't cancel the other.

Per [MSDN Site for MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx)

> Although this routed event seems to follow a bubbling route through an
>   element tree, it actually is a direct routed event that is raised
>   along the element tree by each UIElement.

Comment: If it were a direct event it wouldn't trigger both handlers in the first place, right?

Comment: @Jon I was actually looking at something on MSDN about this earlier today - looking for the link now. Although the events appear to be tunneled/bubbled, they're actually direct.

Comment: @Rachel does that explain why they have "Preview" equivalents? In case you want to handle an even on its way down the tree?

Comment: @djacobson I think the main reason for the Preview equivalents is to catch events before they occur for custom processing. Some Preview events are still direct events (such as `PreviewLeftMouseButtonDown`, which was the one I was looking at earlier)

Comment: This looks like a nice clean solution but I'm seeing e.OriginalSources of 'System.Windows.Controls.Border' or 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' when I click on the GroupBox.

Answer (score 1):

you should handle e.Handled in the PreviewDoubleClick because tunneled events happens before bubbled up ones.

also why would you need to handle that event in both textbox and groupbox ? as it is getting fired in both because 2 separate events are getting fired.