# Embedded ComboBox in Button, but Button steals click event when activating drop down

Tags: wpf, button, combobox, click

I have an application with limited screen space, so I'm trying to conserve some real estate by putting a combo box within a button.  Its pretty nifty and it looks exactly like what I wanted it to look like.  The problem is, every time I click the down arrow on the combo box, the Button also receives a click event. The drop down menu still works properly, but my button has already fired before I've had a chance to actually select what I wanted.

Here is my WPF code that describes my Button and its contents.

```
<Button FontSize="14" Height="32" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="DisableCopierButton_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Disable Copier:" />
        <ComboBox Name="DisableCopierComboBox">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

My question is, when I'm clicking on the ComboBox and only the ComboBox, how do I prevent the click event from passing through the button that is underneath it?

Comment: You may want to look at some WPF SplitButton implementations. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfSplitButton.aspx), [HERE](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SplitButton&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it. I went with the solution provided by Rachel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488187/how-to-prevent-clicks-from-passing-through-a-control-to-the-one-below-it), even though it was not selected as the answer.

```
private void EnableCopierButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (!(e.OriginalSource is Button))
   {
      // combo box was clicked, not the button, so get out of here.
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a SplitButton, yeah.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  Plenty of implementations on the web.
I recommend [WPF Toolkit Extended's](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SplitButton&referringTitle=Home).

Comment: Um, not really interested in importing a third party solution so that I can place a combo box in a button.  There is a way to do this, I'm sure.

Comment: Right-o. There are plenty of other solutions on the internet as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the combo box be part of the button's Content, you may want to try creating a ContentTemplate for the button that includes a combo box.