# Having a clickable element in accordion header

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a checkbox inside of the accordionitem's header. However, when I click a checkbox, it collapses or expands the accordionitem. Is there a way to click the checkbox without the accordion expanding/collapsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found similar problem, different context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488187/how-to-prevent-clicks-from-passing-through-a-control-to-the-one-below-it).
For my particular case:

in xaml we add click event to the checkbox

```
<Accors:AccordionItem>
  <Accors:AccordionItem.Header> 
    ...
     <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click_1"/>
    ...
  </Accors:AccordionItem.Header>
</Accors:AccordionItem>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void CheckBox_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Accordion.SelectionMode property to all available enums. I had faced the same problem working with accrodion but it got resolved when i changed property value to None or some other available enum.

Answer (score 0):

If the Header content contains any controls then ensure that the selection mode is ZeroOrMore
SelectionMode="ZeroOrMore"